# javascript removeChild then replace this with new text using insertBefore

Tags: javascript, function, modularity, removechild

I want to create a function in an external javascript file that I can reuse later (i.e. a modular function that is general enough to be used in whatever javascript it is needed in).  I want to do this with pure JavaScript, not using jQuery or innerHTML.

I want this modular function to do the following:
  1) remove an element of a child
  2) replace this child with the new child value

For example say you had this code:

```
<p id="removeMe">This text needs to be removed</p>
<p id="nextPara">This is the paragraph that follows the replaced paragraph</p>
```

So I need to:

```
  1) parentNode.removeChild(removeMe);
  2) var replacementParagraph = document.createElement('p');
  3) var replacementParagraphText =document.createTextNode("This is the replacementParagraph text);
  4) replacementParagraph.appendChild(replacementParagraphText);
```

Now I just need to figure out how to write the modular function sort of like below:

```
function removeReplace (parameter, parameter) {
   1) remove the child of the paragraph with the id of "removeMe"
   2) use insertBefore(newText, nextPara) to replace the child that was removed in step 1
}
```

Thank you so much for your help, Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, it's much easier because this function already exists natively: [`.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.replaceChild). Actually you've already got the algorithm, you just would need to write it in javascript:

```
function replaceElementByParagraph(id, text) {
    var toremove = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!toremove) // in case no element was found:
        return false; // abort
    var para = document.createElement('p');
    para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    return toremove.parentNode.replaceChild(para, toremove);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi.  This seems to be what I need but I can't get it to work